# How to inherit static builder/constructor method in inherited class?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to implement a common interface for static constructers using a Groovy `Closure`. In it, the pattern I'm attempting to implement is:

```
abstract class WithBuilder<T> {
    static T with(Closure<T> builder) {
        Class<T> clazz = T;
        return with(clazz, builder);
    }
    
    static <T> T with(Class<T> clazz, Closure<T> builder) {
        T arg = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        
        builder.delegate = arg;
        builder.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY;
        
        return builder(arg);
    }
}
```

As any experienced Java developer might note, the syntax `Class<T> clazz = T` isn't valid because `T` is a type signature and not an actual class definition. In the meantime, I've taken to putting an error there `throw new Error('Not implemented');` but in doing so I lose the common interface of the `with` method being a required implementation, and that any subclass of `WithBuilder` should return a new instance of the class.

Any tips on how to get this would be appreciated. I'm trying to build a fluent builder that would look like this in practice:

```
import pipeline.Configuration
import pipeline.Credentials
import pipeline.languages.SupportedLanguages

Configuration.with {
    language SupportedLanguages.Java
    credentials Credentials.get('user')
    environments {
        dev()
    }
}
```

Note: the above is not quite code, but it's the direction I'm aiming for how I want this to work. I'm still learning about Groovy Closures, so the above might not be valid, but I've been inspired by the Jenkins declarative syntax and so I'm aiming for something like that.

### Edit #1

A helpful comment pointed out I was missing a clarification. They thought the missing type parameter on a static method was an accident, but it was somewhat intentional, though I forgot to call out that I know it won't work that way. The reason for it is I want the inherited class to be able to use it like this:

```
class MyClass extends WithBuilder<<MyClass> {
    @Override
    static MyClass with(Closure<MyClass> builder) {
        return with(MyClass, builder);
    }
}
```

However, in my case, I get a warning that `Method does not override method from its super class`

Comment: The first method is missing a type parameter; should be `static <T> T with(Closure<T> builder)`

Comment: Besides that, there is no way to do `Class<T> clazz = T;` in Java because of how generics work (type erasure).

Comment: @Jesper thanks for the comment. I added an edit to clarify my intent, but you are right that the static method is missing a type parameter. I'm trying to avoid that if I can, since I want the return type to be the inheriting class, rather than allowing the user to specify

Comment: Can you override static methods in Java now?

Comment: @DaveNewton maybe not. I come from Python, C#, and JavaScript/TypeScript. Java and Groovy are just the next stepping stones for me. As such, I can't be certain what features are things I expect from other languages but aren't possible in the current one.

Comment: can't override static methods since method overriding relies on dynamic binding at runtime, but static methods are bonded at compile time with static binding. However if you are in groovy - you could define new methods for a Class object - they will look like a static...

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is no need for inheritance. This would work:

```
class Helper {
    static <T> T with(Class<T> clazz, Closure<?> builder) {
        T arg = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

        builder.delegate = arg;
        builder.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY;
        builder(arg)

        return arg; // not builder call result, but delegate
    }
}

class MyClass {
    int a

    static MyClass with(@DelegatesTo(MyClass.class) Closure<?> builder) {
        return Helper.with(MyClass.class, builder);
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "MyClass [a=$a]"
    }
}

println MyClass.with {
    a = 1
}
```

And output:

```
MyClass [a=1]
```

Comment: That is a solution I hadn't considered, but it's not quite what I was hoping for. It's a good intermediate solution, as it removes the problem of DRY principles, but I was hoping to allow inheritance to handle the problem. Also, great call on the decorator. I keep forgetting that's an option

Comment: I guess to clarify on my point, this is an implementation that will be common across multiple classes, and not just the one provided in the sample. A one-line static method is pretty reasonable for implementation, so it's still a very good approach to the problem

Comment: there is no such thing like `override static methods` in Java-based languages. static methods belong to specific classes  = to objects/instances of `Class` type. thus, while static methods of the parent class could be accessed through a child class, it's  not a real inheritance, but a dubious syntax sugar.

Answer (score 1):

i know that i'm not answering the question. just trying show alternative way to achieve the goal described in question.

---

groovy way to declare a metaclass method on a `Class` class - so, `with` method will appear on any `Class` ref:

```js
Class.metaClass.with={Closure builder->
    var arg = delegate.newInstance()
    builder.delegate = arg
    builder.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    builder(arg)
    return arg
}

//test with custom class
class MyClass {
    int abc
}

assert 123 == MyClass.with{ 
    abc=123
}.abc

//test with standard class
assert 'abc-123' == StringBuilder.with{
    it << 'abc' << '-' << 123
}.toString()
```

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_metaclasses

Comment: That's really cool. I read about `metaClass` but couldn't quite figure out how to implement it properly. I might just mark this as the answer after I try it out

Comment: cool solution for small projects. however in large one or in shared library consider this approach with caution, it could bring more harm then good.